# iOS 17 UIKit TabBar Item Animation

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, ios17, sf-symbols

I have an App with a 5 item TabBar built with InterfaceBuilder.
Each item has an SF Symbol as well as a text title.
In iOS 17 with SwiftUI one can apply an SFSymbol animation to an item tap event.  Can someone please tell me how I can apply a symbol effect to tabbar items in UIKit?

The following doesn't work:

```
if #available(iOS 17, *) {
  let house = UIImage(systemName: "house")
  house.addSymbolEffect(.pulse, options: .default, animated: true)
  self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].image=house
}
```

because as a required UIImage, there is no context for addSymbolEffect!